"If possible, you want to avoid alcohol." (want to or wanna; is there any difference?

If possible, you want to avoid alcohol.

My dictionary says this sentence is equal to "If possible, you should avoid alcohol."
But one question arose in my mind: If I contract 'wan to' to 'wanna' in the context where the meaning of 'want to' is 'should', is it still not amiss?
Coming back to question, can I say or write "If possible, you wanna avoid alcohol."?

Using you want to [verb] to mean you should [verb] is an inherently sloppy / casual form anyway. If you wanna make it even more informal, fill your boots. But you certainly won't sound like someone giving out professional advice.

@FumbleFingers  Thanks Fumble. Your advice is as helpful as ever.

As pointed out below, being non-standard, its use should be limited to casual conversation. And even if that's how you talk, I'd advise you to avoid the written version except in extremely informal contexts. Contractions like I'd and can't are perfectly natural in most non-formal written contexts, but when actually written down, wanna usually looks a bit ignorant to most people.

The practical meaning of "You want to" in advice-giving contexts is, indeed, "You should...".  You want to keep that leg elevated with an ice-pack on the knee.   A player on the basketball team might say to another player "You wanna keep that leg elevated.." or even "You're gonna wanna keep that leg elevated..."

It's not necessarily casual. What it is, is spoken not written. Also, it can be less harsh than, say, do not fail to keep that leg elevated. It can be diplomatic in that sense and TimR's example is a very good one. [wanna is just the written form of how some people say it]

The contraction of "want to" into "wanna" is mostly a verbal contraction only - that is - it is (almost) never written as "wanna." "Wanna" is not a "correct" contraction in Standard English, and while it is spoken commonly in American English, it is seen as informal. In most cases, even if someone would say "wanna" they will write "want to"
Wanna in Written Text
When "wanna" appears in written English, it is typically emphasizing the dialect, accent, or informality of the speaker or author. For example, it is commonly used by fiction authors to show a character as informal, childish, or as coming from a rural area. Some songs use it to show a casual, fun tone, like "If you Wanna be Happy" by Jimmy Soul or "If you Wanna be my Lover" by the Spice Girls.
Wanna is also common in African American Vernacular English (AAVE) and may be written down as "wanna" to convey that the speaker/author is using AAVE.
Your Example
In your example, it depends on the formality and context. For example, a medical publication (like information about a prescription or instructions from a doctor's office) would always say "You should avoid.." to be most clear and formal.
A doctor verbally or a friend texting a friend might say "You want to avoid.." as that is very common wording.
In most regions you would not find a doctor that says "You wanna avoid..." but that phrase would be common among friends verbally. However, if they were writing it down or texting each other, they would most commonly spell out "You want to"

Most of my American friends appear to believe that there's only one "t" in the word "twenty" and that there's a "d" in "thirty".

@RonaldSole yes, in many American accents, middle-of-word "t"s often are pronounced without aspiration (such that they sound like a "d"). It is also common for middle-of-word "t"s to be dropped completely in informal conversation.

In casual speech "want to" can be pronounced "wanna". This can happen in any context in which the words "want to" are not emphasised, which could include your example
Unless you are trying to represent the sound of a particular spoken utterance (for example when writing lyrics, and so the rhyme matters) you shouldn't use the spelling "wanna" in written text.

The word wanna is stated in Cambridge Dictionary as
'not standard'.   It is

short form of "want to" or "want a"

Used in this example

If possible, you wanna avoid alcohol?

it should convey the same message as want to does, that is, you should avoid alcohol.
However,  being non-standard, its use should be limited to casual conversation.
wanna
